# How can I check if file type exists in folder

Tags: shell

how can I check if multiple files of a certain type exists in shell script?
I've tried this:

```
[ -e $HOME/somefolder/Images/*.jpeg ] && echo "ok"
[ -f $HOME/somefolder/Images/*.jpeg ] && echo "ok"
```

but in both cases I got:

```
[: too many arguments
```

Comment: What if you use braces? `[ -e "$HOME/somefolder/Images/*.jpeg" ]`

Comment: then it doesn't show any error but also doesn't print the "ok"

Comment: You cannot verify multiple files with this syntax.

Comment: You can use for example a 'for' loop to check files one by one or test the number of 'jpeg' files, if greater than '0' you display 'OK'

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below. `find` is an excellent utility.

```sh
test -n "$(find $HOME/somefolder/Images/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpeg' -print -quit)" && echo "ok" || echo "not ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider the pure-bash solution.

```
if [ "$(shopt -s nullglob ; echo /path/to/file*.jpeg)" ] ; then
  ...
fi
```